# How can I change the navigation bar icon color when my app comes back into focus?

Tags: android, flutter

In my app, I can set the status bar and navigation colors fine. However, I have multiple screens and when a user, for example, presses their home button on their device and then resumes the app later, how can I change the color of the navigation bar when they resume?

My specific issue is my navigation bar background color is white and when I exit the app and resume it later, the icons turn white which makes them impossible to see. Here's my build method (stripped of unnecessary code). I don't change the colors anywhere except here.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.white,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
    systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  ));
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      title: Text("App"),
      centerTitle: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
    body: Container(),
  );
}
```

Below is a picture of my app with the white navigation bar icon color.[image: actual result]

Here's an image of what it should look like[image: expected result]

Comment: Could you add sample code and more details?

Comment: @Benjamin, it's odd that your icon turns white unless you're setting it to white somewhere. Providing your code would be helpful in debugging this.

Comment: I have edited my question @Pro

Comment: @Benjamin, great. so which icon turns to white when you resume?

Comment: In the screenshot, the navigation bar icons are all white...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like normally?

Comment: I've added the screenshot you've requested @Pro.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204234/discussion-between-pro-and-benjamin).

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Benjamin, i was able to recreate your issue on Pixel 2. It's odd and this must be some kind of system bug but you can fix it by setting your bottom system navigation menu color again when your app resumes from background. For that, you need to check your [AppLifeCycleState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html) as shown below,

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.white,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text("App", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.info_outline,
            color: Colors.grey,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I know about AppLifecycleState I was just hoping there was another way so that I didn't have to put this code on every class.

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately, i am not sure if there is an alternative to this. You might wanna post an issue on Flutter GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same issue. My workaround is the last if statement in the code below

```
FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(
  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
);

FlutterStatusbarcolor.setNavigationBarColor(
  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
);

if (MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context) == Brightness.dark) {
  FlutterStatusbarcolor.setNavigationBarWhiteForeground(true);
} else
  FlutterStatusbarcolor.setNavigationBarWhiteForeground(false);
```